# RecyclerView with LayoutBinding - Swipe to remove - Leaves empty space of item size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have searched a lot online but apparently unable to find answer.  I have a todo list, and the adapter has swipe functionality attached, so when someone swipes the item it removes the item from the list.

The problem is that the item that is removed is replaced by new item, but that area is shown as empty area.

[image]

I know there is row item there but does not show up, if I close app and open again it will show up.

Here is my adapter class.

```
@Suppress("NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS")
class TodoAdapter(var allTodos: ArrayList<Todo>, var callback: iTodoAdapter)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>(),
ItemTouchHelperCustomListener {

//Hello
override fun onItemDismiss(position: Int) {
    callback.onDelete(position)
}

override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) : Boolean {
    callback.onItemsSwapped(fromPosition, toPosition)
    return true
}

override fun updateDatabasePositions(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    val size = allTodos.size - 1
    for (index in 0..size) {
        allTodos.get(index).position = index
    }
    callback.onPositionsUpdated()
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) : TodoViewHolder {
    val binding = LayoutTodoItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return TodoViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return allTodos.size
}

private fun createOnClickListener(position: Int) : View.OnClickListener {
    return View.OnClickListener {
        val checked = (it as CheckBox).isChecked
        allTodos.get(position).isSelected = checked
        allTodos.get(position).let { callback.onItemUpdated(it) }
    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(allTodos.get(position), createOnClickListener(position))
}

//We only have 1 type of item
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

class TodoViewHolder(private val binding : LayoutTodoItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(todoItem : Todo?, clickListner: View.OnClickListener) {
        binding.apply {
            setTodoItem(todoItem)
            onClickListener = clickListner
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}

fun getData() : ArrayList<Todo> {
    return this.allTodos
}


interface iTodoAdapter {
    fun onDelete(position: Int)
    fun onItemsSwapped(from: Int, to: Int)
    fun onPositionsUpdated()
    fun onItemUpdated(item: Todo)
}
}
```

Here is my iTodoAdapter implemented in my fragment

```
override fun onDelete(position: Int) {
    viewModel.delete(allTodos.get(position))
}

override fun onItemsSwapped(from: Int, to: Int) {
    Collections.swap(allTodos, from, to)
    rcyTodo?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onPositionsUpdated() {
    viewModel.updateAll((rcyTodo?.adapter as TodoAdapter).getData())
}

override fun onItemUpdated(item: Todo) {
    viewModel.update(item)
}
```

Here is my fragment setup:

```
    val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(rcyTodo.context,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
    rcyTodo.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)

    rcyTodo.apply {
        adapter = TodoAdapter(allTodos, this@Todo)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }

    setupSwipeToDelete()
    setCurrentItems()
```

Here are the functions

```
private fun setupSwipeToDelete() {
    val itemTouchHelperCallback = ItemTouchHelperCallback(rcyTodo.adapter as TodoAdapter)
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rcyTodo)
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
private fun setCurrentItems() {
    viewModel.getAllTodos().subscribe({
        allTodos.clear()
        allTodos.addAll(it)
        rcyTodo?.recycledViewPool?.clear()
        rcyTodo?.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }, {

    })
}
```

I found somewhere that clearing a pool (rcyTodo?.recycledViewPool?.clear()) should redraw items but does not work.

I am thinking do I have to remove layout binding and do it in simple way? is there a way around it? am I missing something? By the way the empty space does have item, this only happens when I remove one item after swiping. Something to do with drawing elements, somehow recycler view thinks this position is should be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `notifyDataSetChanged`, call one more function on the adapter - `notifyItemRemoved(position)`. The documentation says:

> Notify any registered observers that the item previously located at the position has been removed from the data set. The items previously located at and after position may now be found at oldPosition - 1.

Hope it works out :-)

Comment: thanks so much .. it worked even though I had tried that before and it did not work at that time... I think I was calling notifyItemRemoved(position) before item was actually deleted.. and when my flowable was restarting list item it was still having some issues.

Comment: Happy to be helpful :-)